# How to set user session time limit in ldap using php?

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

I want to set active user session limit in ldap using php code at the time of creating users.

```
$ldap_conn = ldap_connect($ldap_server);// connect ldap server
ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die ("Could 
not set LDAP Protocol version");
ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT, 3) or die ("Could not set 
LDAP Protocol version");
if($ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $username, $password) == true)
{      // bind the ldap if bind then set parameters  
$adduserAD["cn"] = $name;
$adduserAD["givenname"] = $name;
$adduserAD["sn"] = 'Kumar';
$adduserAD["sAMAccountName"] = $name;
$adduserAD['userPrincipalName'] = $uname;// log on name
$adduserAD['initials'] = 'Mr';
$adduserAD["objectClass"] = "User";
$adduserAD["displayname"] = "Test User";
$adduserAD['mail'] = $email;// email
$adduserAD['description'] ='We are testing';
$adduserAD["userPassword"] = $pwd;
$adduserAD["userAccountControl"] = "66080"; //enable or disable user..512 
66080 389,66048,636,544,
$base_dn = "cn=".$name.",OU=Netmc,DC=xyz,DC=local"; base domain name
// Attempt to add the user with ldap_add()
if(ldap_add($ldap_conn, $base_dn, $adduserAD) == true){// user creation
echo "User is created";    
}
ldap_close($ldap_conn);        
}else{
echo "Not connected with server";
}
```

User is created successfully but session time is not set. I don't how to 
set session time limit in ldap at the of user creation. Please guide me to 
solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "session time"?

Comment: An ldap backend is just a database, there is no session created when you add a user entry, just entry's data being written into db. Though, you might be able to handle user session when user authenticates - via ldap or whatever - just use [PHP's session handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: I mean when user is created by above code then log on with that user name and now I want to log off user automatically on specific time.